# Adjusting box height to the document bottom

Tags: tikz-pgf, dimensions

I made a command that prints a gray rectangle in my document. I can use this command typing:

`\notes{100}`, where 100 is the vertical size of the box.

```
\newcommand{\notes}[1]{
\begin{minipage}{0.974\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [ draw,
    gray!20,
    rectangle,
    fill=gray!20,
    rounded corners,
    text badly centered,
    text width=\linewidth,
    minimum height=#1 mm
] (init) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\par
}
```

I'm looking for a solution that fills the page to the bottom, getting the size of the `\vfill`.

EDIT: obviously, I need a solution that doesn't need to use some value as parameter.

Comment: Do you want to fill the remainder of the page after the command with the gray rectangle or print the rectangle and fill all space that is left (with whitespace)?

Comment: Hi user13596. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: I want to make the gray rectangle expands until the end of space. I want no blank spaces after the command.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution (using the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package and the `overlay` and `remember picture` options). **Note**: Several compilation are needed!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\vfillgrayrectangle{%
  \par\noindent%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[gray!20,rounded corners]
    (0,0) rectangle (current page text area.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \newpage
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\vfillgrayrectangle
\lipsum[3]
\vfillgrayrectangle
\lipsum[5-8]
\vfillgrayrectangle
\lipsum[2]
\vfillgrayrectangle
\lipsum[4]
\vfillgrayrectangle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was about to answer exactly the same, but without `[yshift=1mm]`. Why is this needed?

Comment: @JLDiaz This is an oversight...

Comment: I’d add a `\par` to the beginning of the definition, so that `\vfillgrayrectangle` can be used directly following some text. (`\lipsum` inserts a `\par` automatically. Try it with `\lipsum*` instead.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel It's a good advice. Thanks. I edited my answer.